# Laravel 7: remove indices from an array passed in Postman

Tags: arrays, laravel, indices

I am passing this JSON text to my Postman as follows:

```
{
    "shop_id": "1",
    "customer_phone_number": "09277174177",
    "products": [{
        "quantity": 2,
        "product_id": 7
    },
    {
        "quantity": 5,
        "product_id": 8
    }]
}
```

When I use `dd($request->products);`, it gives me the result:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "quantity" => 2
    "product_id" => 7
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "quantity" => 5
    "product_id" => 8
  ]
]
```

I am iterating over the list of arrays but I want to remove the indices so it should output like:

```
array:2 [
  {
    "quantity" => 2
    "product_id" => 7
  },
  {
    "quantity" => 5
    "product_id" => 8
  }
]
```

How is this possible? I have tried using `json_encode($request->products);` but it returns a string instance.

Comment: check like this `return $request->products` .. what king of data structure return

Comment: [
    {
        "quantity": 2,
        "product_id": 7
    },
    {
        "quantity": 5,
        "product_id": 8
    }
]

Comment: are your problem solve ?

Comment: I was a little dumbfounded but thanks I forget to return the actual value and was just dumping the data the entire time.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor how do I make it so that when I dump this data, it results to what is returned? the ``dd`` and ``return`` commands are different. Like if i ``dd($request->products);``, it would output: ``[ { "quantity": 2, "product_id": 7 }, { "quantity": 5, "product_id": 8 } ] ``

Comment: dd function print and die .. return  keyword only use for return original value...

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I see, thanks for the clarification mate. :D

Comment: Sorry again, but in this image, I see the array index in the results array of products. https://imgur.com/5UyfEMI.

Comment: image is different object... what do you want to do ?

Comment: If its possible to not show the indices on output. I've checked out that Collections could not do the same as it involves removing indexes and output its value but the index number would still show up. I would have gone with ``json_encode($array)`` but it returns a string instead. Oh well. :( thanks for everything. sorry for being unclear. I think it's just not that possible.

Comment: array flat function .. search it .

Comment: are your problem solve ?